# Remove those with a property not in a collection with commons-collections

Tags: java, collections, filtering, apache-commons, predicate

Say I have a collection of `foodGroupIds` and a collection of `food`. Using commons-collections, how can I filter out the food which does not belong to any of the food groups?

I might be on the right track, but can't figure out what predicate to use. Maybe have to create my own?

```
Collection<Long> ids = collect(
    findGoodFoodGroups(),
    invokerTransformer("getId"));

Collection<Food> food = getAllFood();
filter(food, transformedPredicate(
    invokerTransformer("getFoodGroupId"),
    ?));
```

In C# this would be something like this:

```
var ids = FindGoodFoodGroups().Select(x => x.Id);
var goodFood = FindAllFood().Select(x => ids.Contains(x.FoodGroupId));
```

I want all objects whose property `P` of type `T` is equal to any `T` in a collection `C` with objects of type `T`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use [Collection.removeAll(Collection)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

Simple examples:

```
    Map food = new HashMap();
    food.put("appleKey", "apple");
    food.put("orangeKey", "orange");
    food.put("tomatoKey", "tomato");

    Set unmatchedKeys = new HashSet(food.keySet());
    unmatchedKeys.removeAll(Arrays.asList("orangeKey"));
    System.err.println(unmatchedKeys);

    Collection unmatchedValues = new ArrayList(food.values());
    unmatchedValues.removeAll(Arrays.asList("apple", "tomato"));
    System.err.println(unmatchedValues);
```

Output is:

```
[appleKey, tomatoKey]
[orange]
```

Comment: Hm. With strings it would be more like if you had a list of arbitrary numbers and then wanted to remove those strings which does not have a length equal to any of those numbers.